# Disappearing Apps

Tags: appmenu

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my new comp. I was looking through the apps, tried one out and when I went back into the apps menu, over 50% of my apps were gone. I have looked through everything and can not bring them back. If I go into Ubuntu Software, it shows them as installed, but I have to look them up by name and I am not familiar with all the app names yet.

Comment: I've seen this too on my fresh install of 18.04 and I've confirmed that when it happens that "Frequent" is not selected.  This issue seems to come and go.  I can't reproduce it at will.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the "*All*" button at the bottom of your "Show Applications" screen to see all the installed applications instead of just the frequent ones.

[image]

Comment: I have All selected and they are still gone. I've rebooted multiple times since then and it hasn't resolved itself.

Comment: @MeMyselfandI Then probably somehow contents of your `/usr/share/applications/` directory have got removed/modified.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to do a fresh install. I'm thinking something glitched. Some of the other programs are not working quite right.